# android moving form FORM1 to FORM2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In android application development how to add another activity and link it with the first activity please give an step by step procedure to follow or any tutorial guide if possible

i mean of connecting one activity with another activity

if it is with java code please give any links for reference

i am using eclipse integrated development environment.

Comment: Question is lacking any information or code to suggest you even attempted to do this. First off we are unsure of the circumstance regarding whether you want to pass the information from one activity to the other (or form as you seemed to have called it.)

Comment: @BobMcboberson sorry friends since am a noob in android application development i asked such a silly question...so how will i create a new activity in eclipse in the existing project and how will i link both??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strife in android You can't say Form. you have to say Activity. bellow is the code to move one activity to another

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

Comment: thanks friend since am a noob i ask such silly questions...thanks for bearing with me:-)

Comment: @Harsh Trivedi su vat 6e bhai... jordar....